# Solve the given Cauchy problem on the bounded interval

Tags: partial-differential-equations

$$u_{tt}-16u_{xx}=0, \quad 0<x<3, \quad 0 < t < \infty,$$
$$u(x,0)=x(3-x), \quad u_t(x,0)=\cos(\pi x), \quad 0<x<3,$$
$$u(0,t)=u(3,t)=t, \quad 0 < t < \infty.$$

Determine $u(x,t)$ in terms of x and t for $(x,t)$ in regions 1, 2 , and 3 determined by the characteristics.

So I know for region 1 $u(x,t)$ can simply be found using d'Alembert's solution. What I am not sure of is for regions 2 and 3. Suppose $P: (x,t)$ is in region 2. You form a characteristic quadrilateral having one vertex on the line $x=0$ and two vertices on the piece of the characteristic from the origin bounding region 1. You can find this by $u(P)=u(A)+u(B)-u(C)$ where A is on x=0 and C and B are on the piece of the characteristic from the origin bounding region 1. I have how you find u(A), u(B), and u(C) in my notes, but I do not really understand it.

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

Comment: You have two contradictory conditions for $u(x,0)$.

Comment: What are regions 1, 2, 3?

Comment: @Pragabhava-Region 1 is the triangle that has its base on $t=0$, its left side is $x-4t=0$, and its right side is $x+4t=3$. Region 2 is the triangle that has a side on $x-4t=0$ (the left side of region 1), $x=0$, and $x+4t=3$. Region 3 has a side on $x+4t=3$ (the right side of region 1), $x=3$, and $x-4t=0$. I hope that makes sense.

Comment: @Christopher A. Wong-that was a typo. It was supposed to be $u_t(x,0)=cos(\pi x)$.

Comment: @Sprock Something like [this](http://i.stack.imgur.com/20hCS.png)?

Comment: @Pragabhava-Exactly like that.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For any parallelogram $ABCD$ in the $xt$-plane bounded by four characteristic lines, the sums of the values of $u$ at opposite vertices are equal, that is
$$
u(A) + u(C) = u(B) + u(D)
$$

Let $A = (x,t) \in \mbox{II}$, $B = (0,t_B)$, $C = (x_C,0)$ and $D = (x_D,t_D)$ as shown on the figure:

$\hskip1.5in$[image]

Then $u(x,t) = u(0,t_B) - u(x_C,0) + u(x_D,t_D)$. Now, it's easy to see that
\begin{align}
t_B &= t - \frac{x}{4}\\
x_C &= 4 t - x\\
t_D &= \frac{x}{4}\\
x_D &= 4t
\end{align}

and then the solution on region II is
$$
u(x,t) = u\big(0,t-\tfrac{x}{4}\big) - u\big(4t -x,0\big) + u_I\big(4t,\tfrac{x}{4}\big),
$$
where $u_I$ is the d'Alambert solution in region I.

Can you do region III?

Moreover, can you solve for all time?

Comment: How would the solution change if C and D were on the characteristic line $x-4t=0$?

Comment: @Sprock Now that you know the solution on regions I and II, why dont you take the limit and see it yourself?